# Походження слова "анітелень"

Tags: етимологія

[Мова - ДНК нації](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/inshe/anitelen)

[image]

СУМ-20

> [Анітелень](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=1224&page=52) пред., розм. Варіант слова нітелень, уживаний для
>   підсилення; ні слова, ні звуку.

Цікавить яке походження має дане слово? Адже в ЕСУМ його не знайшла.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В ЕСУМ слово таки є. Ось:

[image]

Отже, це звуконаслідувальне утворення, звідти й походить.

Comment: У мене, чесно кажучи, була асоціація з висловом «не мукає, _не телиться_» (можливо, [російського](//dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/proverbs/32135/) [походження](//phraseology.academic.ru/6761/)). Але ЕСУМ авторитетніший. І не виключено, що навпаки, «не мукає, не телиться» з'явилося порівняно недавно через неправильну інтепретацію слова _(а)нітелень_.